# missing bower_components folder after bower install

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

In a personnal project, I ran this morning `npm install && bower install` after a svn checkout.

All packages seem downloaded and installed with no errors, all fires are green.

But after install, the `bower_components` folder still missing.

I tested a `bower cache clean` but it had no effect.
Also I updated my bower version `# npm -g update bower`, but it had no more effect.

Any idea ?

Here is the bower install output :

```
bower exifreader#*          not-cached git://github.com/mattiasw/ExifReader.git#*
bower exifreader#*             resolve git://github.com/mattiasw/ExifReader.git#*
bower geolocationmarker#*   not-cached git://github.com/shahariaazam/geolocationmarker.git#*
bower geolocationmarker#*      resolve git://github.com/shahariaazam/geolocationmarker.git#*
bower angular#1.2.27            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.27
bower angular#1.2.27          validate 1.2.27 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.27
bower cryptojslib#~3.1.2        cached git://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS.git#3.1.2
bower cryptojslib#~3.1.2      validate 3.1.2 against git://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS.git#~3.1.2
bower ngmap#0.17.0              cached git://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps.git#0.17.0
bower ngmap#0.17.0            validate 0.17.0 against git://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps.git#0.17.0
bower jquery#1.11               cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.2
bower jquery#1.11             validate 1.11.2 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11
bower angularjs-geolocation#~0.1.1           cached git://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation.git#0.1.1
bower angularjs-geolocation#~0.1.1         validate 0.1.1 against git://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation.git#~0.1.1
bower ui-router#~0.2.13                      cached git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#0.2.13
bower ui-router#~0.2.13                    validate 0.2.13 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#~0.2.13
bower angular-bootstrap#~0.12.0              cached git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.12.0
bower angular-bootstrap#~0.12.0            validate 0.12.0 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#~0.12.0
bower angular-ui#~0.4.0                      cached git://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui.git#0.4.0
bower angular-ui#~0.4.0                    validate 0.4.0 against git://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui.git#~0.4.0
bower Bootflat#~2.0.4                        cached git://github.com/bootflat/bootflat.github.io.git#2.0.4
bower Bootflat#~2.0.4                      validate 2.0.4 against git://github.com/bootflat/bootflat.github.io.git#~2.0.4
bower flatstrap3#~3.0.3                      cached git://github.com/littlesparkvt/Flatstrap-for-Bootstrap-3.git#3.0.3
bower flatstrap3#~3.0.3                    validate 3.0.3 against git://github.com/littlesparkvt/Flatstrap-for-Bootstrap-3.git#~3.0.3
bower angular-animate#1.2.27                 cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.27
bower angular-animate#1.2.27               validate 1.2.27 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.27
bower angular-bootstrap-checkbox#~0.3.1      cached git://github.com/sebastianha/angular-bootstrap-checkbox.git#0.3.1
bower angular-bootstrap-checkbox#~0.3.1    validate 0.3.1 against git://github.com/sebastianha/angular-bootstrap-checkbox.git#~0.3.1
bower angular-ui-tinymce#~0.0.5              cached git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce.git#0.0.5
bower angular-ui-tinymce#~0.0.5            validate 0.0.5 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce.git#~0.0.5
bower angular-ui-grid#~3.0.0-rc.16           cached git://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid.git#3.0.0-rc.16
bower angular-ui-grid#~3.0.0-rc.16         validate 3.0.0-rc.16 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid.git#~3.0.0-rc.16
bower geolocationmarker#*                  checkout master
bower exifreader#*                         checkout master
bower geolocationmarker#*              invalid-meta geolocationmarker is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower geolocationmarker#*                  resolved git://github.com/shahariaazam/geolocationmarker.git#36357c8702
bower exifreader#*                     invalid-meta exifreader is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower exifreader#*                         resolved git://github.com/mattiasw/ExifReader.git#84ddc9f7cf
bower bootstrap-sass#~3.0.2               ENOTFOUND Package bootstrap-sass not found
```

Comment: Do you have a .bowerrc file where the directory is set to anything else than /bower_components?

Comment: @Ricconnect No I don't have a `.bowerrc` file.

Comment: Can you post the bower install log?

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have a `.bowerrc` file in your home folder or in a parent folder of the current working directory? The config is obtained from a variety of locations, see: http://bower.io/docs/config/#placement--order

Comment: @drorb oh I just see the last line (ENOTFOUND) and removed the package from the bower.json. Now its okay. The process didn't run at the end, but now its ok. thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved.

the last line of the bower install output :

```
bower bootstrap-sass#~3.0.2               ENOTFOUND Package bootstrap-sass not found
```

caused the exit of the script.

After removed it, its working.